# The database cluster was initialized without USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL but the server was compiled with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to replicate a PostgreSQL 9.6 DB from my openSUSE 64bit machine to my Mint 64bit machine, following the instructions [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/07/setting-up-streaming-replication-postgresql/).

But when I start `psql` on the slave server, I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized without USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL but the server was compiled with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL.
HINT:  It looks like you need to recompile or initdb.
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I'm fine with rerunning `initdb` in the master (there's no important data in it yet) with any settings that are needed to get this to work, but I haven't seen an option in the `initdb` man page to `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL`, and my searches are turning up empty for how to do it.

EDIT:
These are the versions I am using:

```
                                                                     version                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.11-1.pgdg16.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)

                                         version                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.10 on aarch64-suse-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to recompile PostgreSQL to change that.

Usually this setting is determined by the architecture of the machine where PostgreSQL is built — for example, on a 32-bit architecture, you might not have 64-bit integers available.

Perhaps you are trying to replicate between different architectures, or you have a 64-bit PostgreSQL installation on the primary and 32-bit PostgreSQL on the standby.

That won't work.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  I added the versions I'm using.  They are both 64bit, but one is for ARM and one is for x86_64.  Would that be the issue, and could compiling it manually allow it to work?

Comment: I don't know enough about hardware architecture to answer that with certainty. Were the installation packages for both machines taken from the same source?

Comment: Initially I had used the packages from their respective default repositories (e.g. apt install postgresql9.6 from Mint and zypper install postgresql96 from OpenSUSE).  But I downloaded and compiled the source code in my OpenSUSE machine and now it is working.