# Dockerized PostgreSQL error with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL on RPI3

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux, armv7

I try to reinstall PostgreSQL with the official image : postgres:11.4-alpine.
Before, this image worked, but I had to reinstall the host OS (Alpine 3.16) on my Raspberry PI 3, and now, my DB is not working.

I installed Alpine 3.16 (RPI version) in diskless mode (wasn't before).

The PG container shows this error :

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2022-06-12 09:00:46.256 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-06-12 09:00:46.256 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL but the server was compiled without USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL.
2022-06-12 09:00:46.256 UTC [1] HINT:  It looks like you need to recompile or initdb.
2022-06-12 09:00:46.257 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Additional information :

```
uname -a
Linux srv-rp3 5.15.41-0-rpi2 #1-Alpine SMP Sat May 21 06:57:56 UTC 2022 armv7l Linux
```

I tried to rebuild image from my RPI but it doesn't change anything (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/899a216e56e49ca7ab1aaae937f1220caace7ce4/11/alpine/Dockerfile)

I tried adding `--disable-float8-byval \` and `--enable-float8-byval \` to the `./configure` command (line 88) but it doesn't change anything...

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/899a216e56e49ca7ab1aaae937f1220caace7ce4/11/alpine/Dockerfile#L81

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have switched between 32/64 bit builds of alpine with your re-install? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658624/the-database-cluster-was-initialized-without-use-float8-byval-but-the-server-was

Comment: Thank you.
It's possible, yes.  I don't remember what I had before. I still have access to the previous partition, but I no longer have /proc/cpuinfo :/
Now, I have 32 bits.

Comment: How can i just run a 32 bit instance and retrieve the data from the old base? I no longer have a backup :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the on a 64bit system the `image: arm32v7/postgres:11.4-alpine`, because you create the database earlier on a 32bit system.

It is also important that you use exactly the same postgres version in your case the 11.4.